# pass variable from one part of code behind to another

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can I set a variable, and then retrieve that variable in another part of a code behind? I am trying to set the variable in the LoginUser_Authenticate section, and then check the variable in the LoginUser_LoginError section.

```
Protected Sub LoginUser_Authenticate(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs) Handles LoginUser.Authenticate

    If (Membership.ValidateUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text)) And (CurrentUser IsNot Nothing) Then

        // set variable

    else

        // set variable

    End If

End Sub
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Protected Sub LoginUser_LoginError(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoginUser.LoginError

    LoginUser.FailureText = "Invalid Username or Password - Please Try Again"

    Dim CurrentUser As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(LoginUser.UserName)

    If (CurrentUser IsNot Nothing) And ***VARIABLE FROM ABOVE*** Then

        If (CurrentUser.IsLockedOut = True) Then
            LoginUser.FailureText = "Your account has been locked - Contact the system administrator"
        ElseIf (CurrentUser.IsApproved = False) Then
            LoginUser.FailureText = "Your account is disabled - Contact the system administrator"
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a property or field, for example with a `Boolean`variable:

```
Private Property IsAuthorized As Boolean

Protected Sub LoginUser_Authenticate(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs) Handles LoginUser.Authenticate
    If Membership.ValidateUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text) AndAlso CurrentUser IsNot Nothing Then
        IsAuthorized  = True
    Else
        IsAuthorized = False
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub LoginUser_LoginError(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoginUser.LoginError
   ' ... '
    If IsAuthorized  Then
       ' ... '
    End If
End Sub
```

[**Properties Overview**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zdfbdt.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)